# Forward boost::variant from a visitor to another

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I want to call a visitor on a boost variant from inside another visitor. Consider the following code:

```
struct visitor1 : boost::static_visitor<>
{
    void operator()(const int& i) const { std::cout << "visitor1:" << i; }
    void operator()(const std::string & str) const { std::cout << "visitor1, string: " << str}
};

struct visitor2 : boost::static_visitor<>
{
    void operator()(const int& i) const
    {
        // apply visitor1 here
        boost::apply_visitor(visitor1(), /* is there a context reference to the variant here? */)
        std::cout << "visitor 2 applied visitor 1";
    }

    void operator()(const std::string & str) const { //... }
};

int main()
{
  boost::variant< int, std::string> v = 5;
  boost::apply_visitor(visitor2 (), v );
}
```

Should output:

```
visitor1: 5
Visitor 2 applied visitor 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take the variant, just call it directly (witout apply_visitor).

If you want to take it *in addition* just use `bind` or similar:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdc3ecdb1f508a3e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct visitor1 : boost::static_visitor<>
{
    void operator()(const int& i) const            { std::cout << "visitor1:"          << i   << "\n"; }
    void operator()(const std::string & str) const { std::cout << "visitor1, string: " << str << "\n"; }
};

struct visitor2 : boost::static_visitor<>
{

    template <typename  Variant>
    void operator()(const int& i, Variant const& v) const
    {
        boost::apply_visitor(visitor1(), v);
        std::cout << "visitor 2 applied visitor 1" << " (int " << i << ")\n";
    }

    template <typename  Variant>
    void operator()(const std::string & str, Variant const& v) const { 
        boost::apply_visitor(visitor1(), v);
        std::cout << "visitor 2 applied visitor 1" << " (string " << str << ")\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    using V = boost::variant< int, std::string>;
    for (V v : { V{5}, V{"something"} })
        boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(visitor2(), _1, boost::ref(v)), v);
}
```

Prints

```
visitor1:5
visitor 2 applied visitor 1 (int 5)
visitor1, string: something
visitor 2 applied visitor 1 (string something)
```

### Alternative Without Bind

If you prefer DIY you can emulate the "bind" easily:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c8ab4da62aa615b)</kbd>**

```
template <typename V>
struct visitor2 {
    typedef void result_type;
    V const* _ref;

    void operator()(const int& i) const {
        boost::apply_visitor(visitor1(), *_ref);
        std::cout << "visitor 2 applied visitor 1" << " (int " << i << ")\n";
    }

    void operator()(const std::string & str) const { 
        boost::apply_visitor(visitor1(), *_ref);
        std::cout << "visitor 2 applied visitor 1" << " (string " << str << ")\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    using V = boost::variant< int, std::string>;
    for (V v : { V{5}, V{"something"} })
        boost::apply_visitor(visitor2<V>{&v}, v);
}
```

Printing

```
visitor1:5
visitor 2 applied visitor 1 (int 5)
visitor1, string: something
visitor 2 applied visitor 1 (string something)
```

### A Stylistic Note:

I like to make the function object Variant-aware, and then you can hide the "double bind":

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8deeb3e6a6ec9201)</kbd>**

```
struct visitor2 {
    typedef void result_type;

    template <typename... Ts>
        void operator()(boost::variant<Ts...> const& v) const {
            return boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(*this, _1, boost::cref(v)), v);
        }

    template <typename Variant>
    void operator()(const int& i, Variant const& v) const {
        boost::apply_visitor(visitor1(), v);
        std::cout << "visitor 2 applied visitor 1" << " (int " << i << ")\n";
    }

    template <typename Variant>
    void operator()(const std::string & str, Variant const& v) const { 
        boost::apply_visitor(visitor1(), v);
        std::cout << "visitor 2 applied visitor 1" << " (string " << str << ")\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    using V = boost::variant< int, std::string>;
    for (V v : { V{5}, V{"something"} })
        visitor2{}(v);
}
```

Prints

```
visitor1:5
visitor 2 applied visitor 1 (int 5)
visitor1, string: something
visitor 2 applied visitor 1 (string something)
```

Comment: Added two stylistic alternatives.